# How to upload base64 image on codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working with php,I am getting Base64 image in api,And i want to save/store
into database and want to upload image into server,how can i do this ?
I tried with following code but getting following error
"failed to open content, Http writer doest not support writetable connections"

```
function imageupload()
{
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);
     $files=file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); 
     $image = base64_decode($files);
     $image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
     $filename = $image_name . '.' . 'png';
     $path = base_url().'upload/blog/';
     file_put_contents($path . $filename, $image);
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error?

Comment: @JacobMulquin at last line (file_put_contents($path . $filename, $image))

Comment: This is happening because you define `$path` using `base_url()`, you should be referencing somewhere in your filesystem, not the public facing webpage

Comment: @JacobMulquin now image is downloading but whenever i try to open image its showing "doest support file type"

Comment: Why are you uploading the images base64 encoded to begin with? If you're doing a normal file upload, you can just upload them "as is". By base64 encoding them, you add roughly 33% to the file size for no reason + you need to decode them again on the server. And are you sure all images will always be PNG's?

Comment: @M.Eriksson I am using base64 because i am using Reactjs and uploading image via api and i dont want to convert every image to png ? kindly give me suggestion to fix this problem

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're doing since you've only posted the PHP part, and it's unusual to send files base64 encoded when sending actual files. Can you please show us the code that uploads the images as well? I think you're mixing concepts here. If you post JSON to your PHP code (which `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE)` suggests), then `$_FILES` will be empty. If you're doing a `multipart/form-data` upload to the server, then `$_FILES` will contain the uploaded files, but then `php://input` won't contain JSON.

Comment: @M.Eriksson you are right i am using multipart form data

Answer (score 0):

Remove `base_url()` from path.

OR

Check this out

jQuery :

```
$(document).on('click', '#upload', function () {
    let form_data = new FormData();
    let data_url = document.getElementById('my_image').toDataURL('image/png');
    data_url = data_url.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|jpeg);base64,/, '');
    form_data.append('uploaded_image', data_url);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload-avatar',
        method: 'post',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false
    });
});
```

PHP :

```
$img = $this->request->getPost('uploaded_image'); // for ci4
$img = $this->input->post('uploaded_image'); // for ci3
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$file_data = base64_decode($img);
file_put_contents(/* my_path and my_file_name */, $file_data);
```